# be at my/his/her+ superlative adjective

Tags: phrase-usage

Hello everyone:

I know that the phrase **be at my/his/her+ superlative adjective** is normally used in a context like this: I am always **at my most peaceful** when I am with her. But I was wondering if I could use it in a context like this: I was **at my most relaxed** when a violent knock on the door shattered my peace.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. The statement "I am at my most [superlative adjective] when [condition]" means that you are at the highest level of that state when the condition is met, or as a result of that condition being met.

So, for instance, "In those days, I was always my most inspired when I had my special paintbrush" would work, and would mean that during the time period you're describing, you experienced the most inspiration when you had your special paintbrush in your possession.

This wouldn't work for the second statement in your question, because it's saying that they attained the highest amount of relaxation as a result of someone shattering their peace with a violent knock on the door. This seems contradictory - you don't usually become more relaxed as a result of someone disturbing your relaxation.